# How can I change a tabHost at the beginning?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-tabhost, android-drawable

When I start the activity, the 3 tabs are in the old tab-style, not with the setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);.

But new style for tabs only comes, After selecting one of the tab.
Here below is my code, Let me know how can I change my code, so that 3 tabs can show the new style?

**Code:**

```
final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("1");
spec.setIndicator("Inventar 1");
intent = new Intent(this, Spielregeln.class);
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec.setIndicator(" ", ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.handwerk, null)));

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("2");
spec.setIndicator("Inventar 2");
intent = new Intent(this, Spielregeln.class);
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec.setIndicator(" ", ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.freunde, null)));

spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("3");
spec.setIndicator("Inventar 3");
intent = new Intent(this, Spielregeln.class);
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec.setIndicator(" ", ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.inventar, null)));

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button); // unselected
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_clicked); // selected

    }
});
```